# How to make a game object display the texture of its material in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I have a material called "RockyMountain" to which I have assigned a specific texture through the inspector, (Main Maps > Albedo property). The shader is set to "Standard" and the rendering mode is set to "Opaque". The other properties have default values. In the preview panel under the properties, the material is displayed appropriately with the texture being applied and all.

The problem is: when I apply this material to any game object, the object does not display the texture of its material. It merely shows a solid color that seems to be a shade of a color in that same texture.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is a Directional Light on the scene. Also, in the "Lighting" tab I have set the properties of "Environment Lighting" to appropriate values.

Comment: I just realized that the texture appears correctly when applied to an object created in Unity. But the object to which I was assigning the material was created in Blender and then exported. That's the difference. Still I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: ola, "an object created in Unity" .. what does that mean? you mean a primitive shape such as a cube, etc?

Comment: really, i think include a screen shot right!  click edit, then click the "Photo" icon to add images to your question

Answer (score 0):

You have to UV unwrap your object first, basically tell the object what it looks like and how textures should be applied. I doesn't know this on its own!

Here's a tutorial to get you started: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics